# How to format js strings to have a Google Sheet/Excel line break in a single cell?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension

**Background**

I'm trying to format some strings using plain JavaScript. It will be copy-pasted to a single cell in Google Sheet with a line break (alt + enter) in between. For example,

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plrlS.png)

**Code**

```
let result = 'info1'
result += ', '         // replace with a line break
result += 'info2'

CopyToClipboard(result)
```

**Problem**

My closest attempt was using Google Sheet equation and char(10)

```
let result = '="info1"&char(10)&"info2"'
```

But since this solution changes the actual data, it's difficult to edit and reuse from the end-user perspective. I thought there must be a simpler way like **/t** and **/n**.

My not so successful tries include:

```
String.fromCharCode(10)

/r //r /n //n /t //t
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash `\` but not slash `/`

`\n`

```js
var result;

result = 'info1'
result += '\n'
result += 'info2'
/* OR */
result = 'info1\ninfo2'
```

Alternative: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
let result = `info1
info2`;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both don't work. ;_; The Sheet ignores the '\n' character and interprets the second one as a bunch of spaces. But still, thank you!